# Why does the mysqli_stmt::get_result() method give an error when passed as a function argument?

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I have written a PHP script that uses `mysqli` to access the rows in the Customers table of a MySQL DB. The script contains the following function:

```
      # Print the rows in the result.
      # Note: $rslt should be of type mysqli_result.
      function print_rslt($rslt)
      {
        # Get the number of rows in the result.
        $num_rows = $rslt->num_rows;

        ...
      }
```

The `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` method returns a value of type `mysqli_result` (or else a boolean `false` on failure).

Hence, I should be able to pass the following method call *directly* to the function:

```
# Note: $stmt_SelCusts is a prepared statement of type mysqli_stmt.
print_rslt($stmt_SelCusts->get_result());
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error, when trying to access `$rslt->num_rows` within the function:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

On the other hand, the problem is solved, when I do the following:

1. Store the method call's result in a variable:

```
     $rslt_SelCusts = $stmt_SelCusts->get_result();
```

2. Then pass the variable to the function:

```
     print_rslt($rslt_SelCusts);
```

As requested, here's the main code. I have omitted some of the site-specific helper code - This helper code is only to connect to the MySQL DB.

```
    <?php

      try
      {
        # ... MySQL DB connection code

        # SQL statement to select rows from the Customers table
        $sql_SelCusts = 
        'SELECT     CustomerID,
                CompanyName,
                Contact,
                email,
                trn_date
                 FROM       Customers
         ORDER BY   CustomerID
             ;';

        # ... MySQL DB connection code

        # Prepare the SQL SELECT statement.
        $stmt_SelCusts = $msi->prepare($sql_SelCusts);

        $stmt_SelCusts->execute();

        $rslt_SelCusts = $stmt_SelCusts->get_result();

        # Print the rows in the result.
        # print_rslt($rslt_SelCusts);           # correct
        print_rslt($stmt_SelCusts->get_result());   # error
      }
      catch (Exception $ex)
      {
        $file = $ex->getFile();
        $line = $ex->getLine();
        $message = $ex->getMessage();
        $code = $ex->getCode();

        error_log("Exception thrown in $file on line $line: 
                  $message [code $code]");

        echo 'Error selecting rows from 
              the Customers table.<br>';
      }
      finally
      {
        $stmt_SelCusts->close();

        $msi->close();
      }
```

Thus, I know how to fix the problem.
But what is the reason for this error, in the first place?

Comment: So `var_dump($rslt)` and see its value.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Can you please show [mcve] that I can copy and paste or use https://phpize.online/

Comment: @Dharman, I have pasted the main code.

Comment: You have `print_rslt($rslt_SelCusts);` commented out but you seem to forgot to comment the line before it too. `$rslt_SelCusts = $stmt_SelCusts->get_result()` needs to commented out too if you are calling it below, otherwise you are calling it twice

Comment: @Dharman, you are 100% right. That was the root cause. In my main program (which is slightly different from the sample I pasted), in fact I was executing the ```get_result()``` method twice.